# vite react + Tailwind no toma colores

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind, vite

estoy realizando un componente usando react, vite y tailwind css, en este componente realizo una consulta a la api de github, la respuesta de esta consulta contiene un color entre otros atributos, ese color trato de asignarlo al componente de tal forma que tome como borde y color de texto ese color, sin embargo al momento de cargar el componente tailwind no toma el color, lo extraño es que si lo ingreso quemado si funciona, mi componente:

```
import { LoadingIcon, useLabels } from "../../../index"

export const LabelPicker = () => {

    const labelsQuery = useLabels()

    if (labelsQuery.isLoading) {
        return <LoadingIcon />
    }

    return (
        <>
            {
                labelsQuery.data?.map(label => (
                    <span key={label.id}                      
                        className={`m-1 inline-block break-words border-[1px] border-solid border-[#${label.color}] rounded-2xl px-2 py-1 bg-transparent text-[#${label.color}] cursor-pointer text-center hover:bg-white/5`}>
                        {label.name}

                    </span >
                ))
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

Al inspeccionar el codigo en mi navegador veo que en la clase del componente se carga debidamente el codigo del color por ejemplo border-[#${label.color}] queda como border-[#FFF], mas sin embargo no funciona, a menos que lo ingrese directmente en el codigo.

comparto tambien mi postcss.config.js y mi tailwind.config.js:
postcss.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

tailwind.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Segun la documentacion:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Si utiliza la interpolación de cadenas o concatena nombres de clases parciales, Tailwind no los encontrará y, por lo tanto, no generará el CSS correspondiente

envia la clase completa

ejemplo:

const colorBorder = 'border-red'

className={`${colorBorder}` }